# Canvas text looks horrible

Tags: text, canvas, fonts, html5-canvas

I have the following code to draw text

```
                ctx.fillStyle="red";
                ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 10, 10);
                ctx.fillStyle="white";
                ctx.font="bold 20px sans-serif"
                ctx.fillText(player.name,player.x,player.y)
```

Unfortunately, it looks horrible.  Really blocky.

[image]

I attempted to shrink it down to 10px, which is the size of the red box, but then it looks even worse.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your canvas size needs to be set internally and not skewed by CSS. That would blur everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the canvas getting scaled by CSS by any chance? If so, that would stretch the text because it is being written to an on-screen bitmap vs directly embedded.

Comment: I set the height and width to 720p in css.  Is that now how to set the dimensions of a canvas?

Comment: You're right.  If I remove the css and set the width and height in html directly, it looks right.